# How to make the menu disappear in a SP hosted app?

Tags: office-365

Is it possible to make the menu disappear? thx!

[image]

Comment: Just something to think about - if you do this you take away the users ability to navigate back to the site where the app was installed (i.e. the host web)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

put following css tag in App.css or in default.aspx

```
#suiteBarDelta {
    display: none !important;
}
#s4-ribbonrow{
display: none !important;
}
```